# Simple factorial program using recursion

Tags: java, beginner, recursion, exception-handling, exception

Two concepts I realized I needed to understand and use more are recursion and Exceptions. Thus, I combined both in the following program. Although it began with a focus on using recursion it became more about Exceptions. I think the recursive part is bare-bones and straight-forward but I would nonetheless appreciate any tips/advice on using/formatting recursion in general.

On exception-handling: Is the following the optimal way of employing them or is there a more conventionally favored fashion? I get the feeling I may be missing doing something unnecessary or missing something important.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

class FactorialDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int factorialNumber = 0;
        try {
            factorialNumber = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                "Which number should we compute the factorial of?"));
        } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Input must be an integer!",
                "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

            throw new NumberFormatException("Input must be an integer.");
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                factorialNumber + " factorial is " +recur(factorialNumber) +".",
                "Result", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }

    public static int recur(int n) {
        int result;
        if (n < 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"n must be >= 0 but was " + n,
                "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

            throw new IllegalArgumentException("n must be >= 0 but was " + n);
        }
        if (n < 2) {
            return 1;
        }

        result = recur(n - 1) * n;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Recursion**

It's good that you are trying to grasp recursion, the more programming patterns you understand, the better.

[But I would disagree that you need to use recursion more often](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15346774/are-recursive-methods-always-better-than-iterative-methods-in-java). Generally, it consumes more memory and iterative solutions tend to be faster as well.

<strike>As for your solution, I think that `if (n == 1)` would be clearer than `if (n < 2)` (also, `n < 2` returns `1` for input `0`, which is wrong)</strike>, and I wouldn't save the return value in `result`, but return it directly.

**Exceptions**

In `recur` throwing an `IllegalArgumentException` makes sense (it is an illegal argument), but showing the dialog here doesn't make that much sense, I would move that to main.

Also, don't throw an exception you just caught without a reason. If you don't want to execute the following function, just put all code in the try and catch the different exceptions.

**Other**

- `recur` isn't a good name. I would call it `factorial` or `factorialRecursive`.
- I would wrap the show message code into a function, that way you could also easily exchange it for something else (like a print). If you then further wrap this up in an object, unit testing would also be easier.

**Code**

If you do all of this, the code would look something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int factorialNumber = 0;
    try {
        factorialNumber = Integer.parseInt(input("Which number should we compute the factorial of?"));
        print(factorialNumber + " factorial is " + factorialRecursive(factorialNumber) + ".",
                "Result");
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        error("Input must be an integer!", "Error");
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
        error(iae.getMessage(), "Error");
    }
}

public static int factorialRecursive(int n) {
    if (n < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("n must be >= 0 but was " + n);
    }
    if (n < 2) {
        return 1;
    }

    return factorialRecursive(n - 1) * n;
}

public static String input(String message) {
    return JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, message);
}

public static void print(String message, String title) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
            message,
            title, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
}

public static void error(String message, String title) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message,
            title, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

Comment: IMO, IllegalArgumentException shouldn't be used this way. This is an exception to show the programmer that **he** did something wrong. The right way of doing it (IMO) is to test the user input before calling the method.

Comment: @Joffrey You wouldn't check the input in `factorialRecursive` at all (and then maybe throw a custom exception which extends `Exception` instead of `IllegalArgumentException`)? I always thought that relying on the calling code to get it right was not the correct approach? Also, my approach is in line with how `parseInt` handles it: If the input is not correct, it throws an unchecked exception. I could imagine adding additional code after parsing the input which checks if it positive, and that seems like a good approach, but also a bit like duplicating functionality.

Comment: IMHO your error method should take the exception and optionally some details as arguments. Passing `"Error"` is redundant.

Comment: @maaartinus It's just a quick example (in real code, I would probably wrap it in a class and structure it quite a bit differently, but here I thought that it would be overkill). But I did think about your solution, and it would simplify the code. But the current error method is more flexible. It can have `Important Error` or `System Error`, or `Exiting` as title instead of an hardcoded `Error` title, and it can also print errors that do not come from exceptions (as it's doing right now in the case of `NumberFormatException`).

Comment: @tim OK, in this case `"Error"` is the additional information I spoke about and everything's alright.

Comment: @tim Sorry I didn't express myself properly. I wanted to say, the `factorialRecursive` method is well written (with a nice IAE) but you shouldn't use IAE to display an error message regarding *user* input. You check for *user* input before calling the method. IAE is here to check for wrong *programmer* input.

Comment: @Joffrey so your saying that the check should happen twice? Once when gathering user input, and once in the method? I guess that that makes sense (maybe not in this small example, but certainly in a bigger application).

Comment: @tim Exactly. In bigger applications, you would write methods like `factorialRecursive` with an IAE security, no matter where it gets its input from. On the other hand, each time you have user input, you test for correctness and send the right error messages before making methods crash with IAE. IAE would be here for you during the tests to ensure you didn't forget to test some user input, or to detect wrong calculations of the input if it is done in your program.

Answer (score 3):

@tim's confusion in his answer indicates that your code could use a comment:

```
public static int recur(int n) {
    int result;
    if (n < 0) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"n must be >= 0 but was " + n,
            "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("n must be >= 0 but was " + n);
    }
    if (n < 2) {//both 0! and 1! are 1
        return 1;
    }

    result = recur(n - 1) * n;
    return result;
}
```

I was quite confused myself too.